# SqlBulkCopy with ObjectReader - Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32

Tags: sqlbulkcopy, fastmember

I am using SqlBulkCopy (.NET) with ObjectReader (FastMember) to perform an import from XML based file. I have added the proper column mappings.

At certain instances I get an error: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

I'd like to understand how to 
1. Trace the actual table column which has failed
2. Get the "current" on the ObjectReader

sample code:

```
     using (ObjectReader reader = genericReader.GetReader())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sbc.WriteToServer(reader); //sbc is SqlBulkCopy instance
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();                           
                    }
                }
```

Does the "ex" carry more information then just the error:
`System.InvalidOperationException : The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column.`

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Answer**

The simple answer is no. One of the reasons `.NET's SqlBulkCopy` is so fast is that it does not log anything it does.  You can't directly get any additional information from the `.NET's SqlBulkCopy` exception. However, that said [David Catriel](https://www.codeproject.com/Members/david-catriel) has wrote an article about this and has delivered a possible solution you can read fully about [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387465/Retrieving-failed-records-after-an-SqlBulkCopy-exc).

Even though this method may provide the answer you are looking for I suggest only using the helper method when debugging as this quite possibly could have some performance impact if ran consistently within your code.

**Why Use A Work Around**

> The lack of logging definitely speeds things up, but when you are
>   pumping hundreds of thousands of rows and suddenly have a failure on
>   one of them because of a constraint, you're stuck. All the
>   SqlException will tell you is that something went wrong with a given
>   constraint (you'll get the constraint's name at least), but that's
>   about it. You're then stuck having to go back to your source, run
>   separate SELECT statements on it (or do manual searches), and find the
>   culprit rows on your own.
>
> On top of that, it can be a very long and iterative process if you've
>   got data with several potential failures in it because SqlBulkCopy
>   will stop as soon as the first failure is hit. Once you correct that
>   one, you need to rerun the load to find the second error, etc.

**advantages:**

1. Reports all possible errors that the SqlBulkCopy would encounter
2. Reports all culprit data rows, along with the exception that row would be causing
3. The entire thing is run in a transaction that is rolled back at the end, so no changes are committed.

**disadvantages:**

1. For extremely large amounts of data it might take a couple of minutes.
2. This solution is reactive; i.e. the errors are not returned as part of the exception raised by your SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer() process. Instead, this helper method is executed after the exception is raised to try and capture all possible errors along with their related data. This means that in case of an exception, your process will take longer to run than just running the bulk copy.
3. You cannot reuse the same DataReader object from the failed SqlBulkCopy, as readers are forward only fire hoses that cannot be reset. You'll need to create a new reader of the same type (e.g. re-issue the original SqlCommand, recreate the reader based on the same DataTable, etc).

**Using the GetBulkCopyFailedData Method**

```
private void TestMethod()
{
   // new code
   SqlConnection connection = null;
   SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = null;

   DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
   // load some sample data into the DataTable
   IDataReader reader = dataTable.CreateDataReader();

   try 
   {
      connection = new SqlConnection("connection string goes here ...");
      connection.Open();
      bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection); 
      bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Destination table name";
      bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
      // loop through all inner exceptions to see if any relate to a constraint failure
      bool dataExceptionFound = false;
      Exception tmpException = exception;
      while (tmpException != null)
      {
         if (tmpException is SqlException
            && tmpException.Message.Contains("constraint"))
         {
            dataExceptionFound = true;
            break;
         }
         tmpException = tmpException.InnerException;
      }

      if (dataExceptionFound)
      {
         // call the helper method to document the errors and invalid data
         string errorMessage = GetBulkCopyFailedData(
            connection.ConnectionString,
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName,
            dataTable.CreateDataReader());
         throw new Exception(errorMessage, exception);
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      {
         connection.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

> GetBulkCopyFailedData() then opens a new connection to the database,
>   creates a transaction, and begins bulk copying the data one row at a
>   time. It does so by reading through the supplied DataReader and
>   copying each row into an empty DataTable. The DataTable is then bulk
>   copied into the destination database, and any exceptions resulting
>   from this are caught, documented (along with the DataRow that caused
>   it), and the cycle then repeats itself with the next row. At the end
>   of the DataReader we rollback the transaction and return the complete
>   error message. Fixing the problems in the data source should now be a
>   breeze.

**The GetBulkCopyFailedData Method**

```
/// <summary>
/// Build an error message with the failed records and their related exceptions.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="connectionString">Connection string to the destination database</param>
/// <param name="tableName">Table name into which the data will be bulk copied.</param>
/// <param name="dataReader">DataReader to bulk copy</param>
/// <returns>Error message with failed constraints and invalid data rows.</returns>
public static string GetBulkCopyFailedData(
   string connectionString,
   string tableName,
   IDataReader dataReader)
{
   StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder("Bulk copy failures:" + Environment.NewLine);
   SqlConnection connection = null;
   SqlTransaction transaction = null;
   SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = null;
   DataTable tmpDataTable = new DataTable();

   try
   { 
      connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
      connection.Open();
      transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
      bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints, transaction);
      bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;

      // create a datatable with the layout of the data.
      DataTable dataSchema = dataReader.GetSchemaTable();
      foreach (DataRow row in dataSchema.Rows)
      {
         tmpDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(
            row["ColumnName"].ToString(), 
            (Type)row["DataType"]));
      }

      // create an object array to hold the data being transferred into tmpDataTable 
      //in the loop below.
      object[] values = new object[dataReader.FieldCount];

      // loop through the source data
      while (dataReader.Read())
      {
         // clear the temp DataTable from which the single-record bulk copy will be done
         tmpDataTable.Rows.Clear();

         // get the data for the current source row
         dataReader.GetValues(values);

         // load the values into the temp DataTable
         tmpDataTable.LoadDataRow(values, true);

         // perform the bulk copy of the one row
         try
         {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(tmpDataTable);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            // an exception was raised with the bulk copy of the current row. 
            // The row that caused the current exception is the only one in the temp 
            // DataTable, so document it and add it to the error message.
            DataRow faultyDataRow = tmpDataTable.Rows[0];
            errorMessage.AppendFormat("Error: {0}{1}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine);
            errorMessage.AppendFormat("Row data: {0}", Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (DataColumn column in tmpDataTable.Columns)
            {
               errorMessage.AppendFormat(
                  "\tColumn {0} - [{1}]{2}", 
                  column.ColumnName, 
                  faultyDataRow[column.ColumnName].ToString(), 
                  Environment.NewLine);
            }
         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex) 
   { 
      throw new Exception(
         "Unable to document SqlBulkCopy errors. See inner exceptions for details.", 
         ex); 
   }
   finally
   {
      if (transaction != null)
      {
         transaction.Rollback();
      }
      if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
      {
         connection.Close();
      }
   }
   return errorMessage.ToString();
```